# "mvn site" searches for libraries not needed to build/test

Tags: maven

I have a Drools-based application that builds and runs perfectly.  Now I'm trying to use "mvn site" on it and it doesn't works: it searches for some jar I haven't in my local repository. I have found one of them on the Internet and installed manually in my repository but now it searches also for

```
org/drools/drools-simulator/7.5.0.Final/drools-simulator-7.5.0.Final.pom
```

and I cannot find it anywhere.  Why these files are needed by "mvn site" only?  And where can I find drools-simulator 7.5.0?

I'm using Maven 3.3.9 and I have added in my root pom the following block:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it could be possible that Maven tries to report dependency information. This happens by default when you use "maven-project-info-reports-plugin" without specifying the kind of report you need. Better define a report set like this:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/examples/selective-reports.html

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: It was caused by the "dependency-management" report: some library has a long BOM that references a lot of jars I don't use.